# Dynamic Tree Data Structure For Improved Dinic's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, network-flow

I want to apply Dinic's algorithm with dynamic tree. But I find very few sources.
especially about the dynamic tree.
It would be great if there is a good source with detailed explains or some simple sources code which uses dynamic tree.

Any one come across something like that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea for improvement is avoiding premature pessimization in Dinic's algorithm. As opposed to preflow/push algorithms, Dinic's algorithm searches for paths in the residual flow graph. Once such a flow is addressed, instead of starting a new search, the modified algorithm deals with paths found in the previous search.

You can find [here](http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~jst/cse/542/text/sec19.pdf) a very readable introduction for this, including an implementation of the data structure itself. [here](http://math.mit.edu/~rpeng/18434/blockingFlows.pdf) is a more detailed lecture. Finally, [A Data Structure for Dynamic Trees (by Sleator and Tarjan)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/dynamic-trees.pdf) is the original paper focussing on the implementation of the data structure itself.

Comment: Actually I have read first two sources quickly before, and did not understand much. But I do understand Dinic's algorithm. Maybe my problem is dynamic tree which I don't know at all. Seems like these are the best resources available, let me go over them again slowly. Thanks!  :)

Comment: @alim Then check the third. I think it is the one you want.

Comment: It's good to give links descriptive titles (the third one is A Data Structure for Dynamic Trees, DANIEL D. SLEATOR AND ROBERT ENDRE TARJAN), so that, when links inevitably rot, Google can help find those things again. In the meantime, I have added those links to the wayback machine. (http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~jst/cse/542/text/sec19.pdf, for example)

Comment: @jbapple Thanks! Modified to a more descriptive link. You're right.