# Algorithm for assigning items to groups based on binary criteria

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, theory

I'm working on an algorithmic problem that has me stumped. It is related to both the assignment problem and maximum cardinality matching. I'll be using it to match large amounts of data so it's important to be fast, ideally O(n<sup>2</sup>) or better.

### Problem Statement

Consider a set of universities U and a set of prospective students S. Assume that |U| << |S|. Each university has a specific number of slots available to admit students, and a binary criteria for whether each student in S is eligible or ineligible to attend. The number of prospective students is equal to the total number of slots available across all universities.

Is there a fast algorithm that will assign students to universities such that:

- Each university admits exactly the number of students they wanted
- Only students eligible for a university will be assigned to that university
- If those conditions are not possible, it will return some value indicating that it was not possible (either a best possible incomplete match for the conditions or just -1/error/etc)

### What I've considered

This can be modeled as a maximum-cardinality bipartite matching problem.

Construct the bipartite as follows:

- Each prospective student is a node
- Each university is a node
- For each university, draw an edge to each eligible student
- Duplicate each university node to represent the number of available slots for that university

The Hopcraft-Karp algorithm can find a maximum-cardinality matching in roughly O(n<sup>2.5</sup>) (where n is the number of students). If the cardinality of the match is equal to the number of students, the problem has been solved. If not, a solution is impossible for the given dataset.

However this approach seems to be inefficient because there are far more students than universities. Each university node has to be duplicated many times, resulting in a huge number of edges for the Hopcraft-Karp algorithm to process.

Is there a better way of abstracting this problem that I'm not seeing? Or is there a clever algorithm that can make use of the fact that there are far fewer universities than students and improve the runtime?

Comment: This can be made into a maximum flow problem. Each student is connected to the source, then to the universities that they can go to, then universities are connected to the sink with their number of slots. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36195440/585411 gives pointers for how to solve this in `O(V E log(V))`  In your case that would be `O(|S|^2 |U| log(|S|))`. If `|U| is smaller than `sqrt(|S|)` this is an improvement.

Comment: @btilly how did you get the complexity ? Just curious, as we could inverse the flow and connect the source to universities, then to eligible students. Would that improve the complexity to `O(|U|^2 |S| log(|U|))` ?

Comment: @AloisChristen The estimate for the algorithm is a standard result. The estimate for this case is just a question of saying that `V = O(|S|)` and `E = O(|S| |U|)`. Since it is vertexes and edges, it doesn't matter which way you direct the water.

Comment: I ended up using SciPy's implementation of Dinic's algorithm. It runs very fast on my data, ~7 seconds for 5 million Students and 26 Universities. The benefit of having to test and maintain less code outweighed the possibility of further algorithmic optimizations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s a simple O(|S| |U|²)-time algorithm, which meets your criterion in the worst case if |U| = O(√|S|) and likely does a lot better than the quoted running time in practice. (See also “bipush” variants of standard flow algorithms.)

The basis of this algorithm is Ford–Fulkerson. For each student in turn, we try to assign them a university. If we’re lucky, one of their choices has capacity, but in general, we need to shuffle other students around to make capacity (find an augmenting path).

Now, what typically makes finding an augmenting path expensive is that we have to traverse the whole graph. However! If we keep a |U|×|U| array where the (i, j) entry is a list of students that can move from university i to university j, then this takes O(|U|²) time (breadth-first search from the set of admissible universities of the new student; we only need to know if each cell of the array is empty). We (re)assign at most |U| students, each of which generates O(|U|) work to update the lists, so the total cost per iteration is O(|U|²).

One nice property of this algorithm in practice (many flow algorithms, actually) is that, if you feed it a partial assignment with k unmatched students, then the running time is O(|S| |U| + k |U|²). The idea would be to find a fast heuristic that does a reasonable but incomplete job (e.g., shuffle the students and try to assign each one to the admissible university that is least popular with other students).

Comment: This strikes me as a good approach.  Before getting down into the details, do a quick feasibility test: check that every university has more or equal eligible students then slots.  If solution is feasible then the calculation can be used to order the universities by popularity to be used in the heuristic mentioned in the last para.

Comment: "we need to shuffle other students around to make capacity" Can you advise on how to choose which assigned student to move and how to choose where to re-assign them.

Comment: @ravenspoint You follow the path found by the BFS. Glossed over that because it's basically the same as regular F–F.

Comment: Any further details would be appreciated.  I know how to code a BFS, but cannot see how a BFS helps here. A path from where to where?  FYI I have implemented the feasibility test and the heuristic. looking to assign the students left out by the heuristic https://github.com/JamesBremner/students2university/blob/main/src/main.cpp

Comment: @ravenspoint from one of the universities that the new student can attend to a university with capacity. Each arc in the path represents a student moving from the tail of the arc to the head of the arc.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not get it.  I understand what an edge in your graph represents, but do not understand how a BFS would be used here.  Anyway, I have developed something much simpler which I believe is a fast and practical solution to this problem - see my answer.

Comment: @ravenspoint you want to find the shortest chain of reassignments that makes capacity for the new student at one of their admissible universities.

Comment: I know what I want to do! How, that is the question!

Comment: @DavidEisenstat is there a name for this variation of Ford-Fulkerson?

Comment: @BrooklynRoseLudlow bipush

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a two stage algorithm that is simple and fast.

There are two stages:

1  A **heuristic** that simply assigns each student to the least popular university that has room and for which they are eligible.  This is based on a suggestion by David Eisenstat

Often this is sufficient to fill all the slots.  When is is not, the second stage runs

2  **MakeRoom** searches for an assigned student that can be moved to another of their eligible universities to make room for a unassigned student.

Here is a typical output for a feasible randomly generated problem

```
random problem generated with 2488 university slots and 2500 students
2270 students assigned by hueristic
218 students assigned by MakeRoom
SUCCESS - all slots filled
```

The application for this is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/students2university

How large are the problems you are dealing with?  If you let me know I can run a timing test on such a problem.  The ~ 2500 slot problem runs in less than a second.

Note that the MakeRoom is not *mathematically guaranteed* to produce a perfect solution where every slot is filled.  Problems can be imagined that would require several students being moved to make room for one more.  However, I have run this many times on small and large problems and, so long as the problem is feasible and there are sufficient students applying, a perfect solution is often found.  I believe this algorithm is suitable for practical use since it is easy to code, runs fast and if not perfect it will fill all the slots almost always and if not will only leave a few unfilled.

What does "sufficient" students mean?  Obviously, these should be more students than slots.  Actually, extra students are required to handle miss-matches between slots available and student eligibilities.  The more students that are available the easier the problem becomes, until the first, heuristic step is able to handle the complete problem.  In my testing I have found that 20% more students then university slots allows large problems to be solved perfectly in very short times.

Some timing measures for problems with 20% 'extra' students

| slots | secs |
| --- | --- |
| 25,000 | 0.006 |
| 250,000 | 0.016 |
| 2,500,000 | 0.11 |
| 25,000,000 | 1.2 |

Note that these times are for running the algorithm.  Inputting the data and outputting the results will add considerably to the times for the larger problems.

Comment: At most, 20 million students and 20 universities. And if it matters, the data will be distributed such that some universities are compatible with almost all students while other universities are compatible with few.

Comment: If there are sufficient students applying ( e.g. 20% more than the available slots ) 20 million slots is feasible - solved perfectly in less than 2 seconds.

Comment: Have you looked at my code?  In particular the problem generator?  It is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/students2university/blob/b588c1d60519b86965a17d21bb7d8f27fc521d1e/src/main.cpp#L98-l130.  Is this anything like your problem?  The numbers are critical for the performance and your question is vague about numbers.  If you could provide the actual specifications of your problem, then I could model it more accurately.

Comment: It looks like this doesn't guarantee a solution, even when a solution is possible for given data. I'm looking for an algorithm that will either definitively solve the problem for a given dataset or show that a solution isn't possible.

Comment: You still haven't told me how long you are willing to wait for a definitive solution to the 2 million slot problem.  It will be many hours at least, probably days.

Comment: Using SciPy's implementation of Dinic's algorithm, it took only ~7 seconds to solve the problem for 5 million students x 26 universities with 5 million slots. I think the real-world performance of the network flow algorithms is much better on this data than the theoretical worst-case. This is because the graphs are straightforward bipartites, the flow capacities of most edges are low, and the number of universities is small compared to the number of students.

Comment: I am skeptical.  If the number of students exactly equals the number of slots, the problem will usually be unsolvable unless every student is eligible for every slot - in which case the solution can be found almost instantly.